# Unable to delete sqlite database

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, sqlite

If I execute a script containing the following and then try to delete mydb on the file system, I am unable to do so until I shut down the python idle. What is the issue here?

```
   with sqlite3.connect(r'./mydb') as connection:
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      cursor.executemany('...' )
      connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlite` connection context manager manages *transactions*, not the connection. The `__exit__` handler commits or rolls back, it does **not** close the connection. See [Using the connection as a context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

> Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions. In the event of an exception, the transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is committed.

You'll have to explicitly close the connection yourself, or use the [`contextlib.closing` context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing):

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(sqlite3.connect(r'./mydb')) as connection:
    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.executemany('...' )
```